# How to assign specific objects of an array into another array of objects?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have array of objects named tickets and I want to pick some specific objects from tickets like number,desc and state and assign them to new array of objects say myarr. I'm writing the below code but it says number is undefined. What am I doing wrong ?

```
$scope.myarr=[{

  number:"",
  desc:"",
  state:""
  }

 ];


 for(var i=0;i<$scope.tickets.length;i++){

  $scope.myarr[i].number=$scope.tickets[i].number;
  $scope.myarr[i].desc=$scope.tickets[i].short_description;
  $scope.myarr[i].state=$scope.tickets[i].state;

 }
```

Comment: initialize your myarr **$scope.myarr=[];**

Comment: What is the condition in your loop ? You said that you want to pick some specific objects, which one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need do something like this.

```
$scope.myarr=[];
for(var i=0;i<$scope.tickets.length;i++){
  //Your Conditions
   var object={
      "number":$scope.tickets[i].number,
      "desc" :$scope.tickets[i].short_description,
      "state":$scope.tickets[i].state
   }
   $scope.myarr.push(object);
}
```

Comment: was this helpful>>

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.myarr = [];
angular.forEach($scope.tickets, function(ticket) {
  this.push({number:ticket.number, state: ticket.state});
}, $scope.myarr);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to support IE < 9, there is a handy function called `map` which is useful in this case

```
$scope.myarr = $scope.tickets.map(function(ticket) {
  // return the element to be inserted in the new array
  return {
    number: ticket.number,
    desc: ticket.short_description,
    state: ticket.state
  };
});
```